# SliverList inside ExpansionTile without Shrinkwrap (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

Is there any way to build a **SliverList** inside **ExpansionTile**?
The reason I want to do this,
I have a really large amount of data that needs to be put inside the expansion tile. Expansion tile needs List but SliverList should be inside **CustomScrollView**. If I use custom Scroll View inside Expansion tile's Children and put SliverList in it renders nothing. If I set **Shrinkwrap** true to CustomScrollView it renders Every Widget at a time.
So, How can it be fixed?

Here is an example,

```
class Expamle extends StatelessWidget {
  const Expamle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        ....,
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (_, i) => ExpansionTile(
              title: const Text('Title'),
              children: [
                // But it is Illegal here
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (_, i) => const Text('Child'),
                    childCount: 10,
                  ),
                ),
                // It does not render anything
                CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: [
                    SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (_, i) => const Text('Child'),
                        childCount: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                // It Works but render all widgets at a time
                CustomScrollView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  slivers: [
                    SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (_, i) => const Text('Child'),
                        childCount: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include more about UI behavior, like what will be the parent and do you want fixed or flexible size for `ExpansionTile`? Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: I think you can create a widget using `Column` for items, while we separate the context it can be handled and parent `CustomScrollView` will handle the overflow

Comment: OverFlow is not a problem here. Problem is, rendering widgets only which are visible to the user. Your solution will render all widgets at once. and it is not good at perfomance.

Comment: `ExpansionTile` seeks `Widget`(not sliverTYpe), while separating the context  improve the performance and  parent `CustomScrollView` build its children on demand

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Refactor `CustomScrollView` with `StatelessWidget` and pass data, then use `Column`, you can test the performance.

Comment: Tried it. But not working. Performance drop.

Comment: Then you can try with creating custom sliver  extending `RenderSliver`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a proper solution but just a rought workaround. I need the same functionality and it seems it can't be achieved with Flutter currently. So I ended up changing the design a bit. Instead of having a full list of data in your expansion tile, you can just show a preview of some small number of items which can be rendered at once safely. Then, at the end of this short list, add a "Show all (number)" button which will show the full data in a separate screen or dialog.

Comment: Please leave a helpfull comment rather then a answer if you have advise like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to achieve what you want: https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_sliver_list

I've had some success with it. But it is not highly customisable. The animation speed is way too slow making it rather laggy feeling. You can potentially just fork or change the code locally to fix this.

However, once the lists expand, they are truly within a sliver. I can feel a massive improvement when the list gets very long. No jitters.